# Visual Studio "SQLBuildTask" task was not given a value for required parameter "DatabaseName" error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, build, compiler-errors

I've got a database project in my solution that keeps failing to build with the following error:

> 04044: The "SQLBuildTask" task was not given a value for required
>   parameter "DatabaseName".

When I double click the error it brings up the following XML:

[image: Buildtask XML]

I can't seem to find a reference to the "DatabaseName" variable although I understand its a system defined SQL CMD variable from the project options, however it won't let me specify a value for it.

I have my own build configuration, and weirdly other build configurations work fine.  Creating a new configuration doesn't work either.  Can anyone shed some light on why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we weren't intending to use anything SQL-related, but found the following line in the .csproj file:-

```
<Import Project="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" Condition="'$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)' == ''" />
```

Removing this line solved the problem. I'm sorry I don't have any more insight than that.

Comment: Brilliant! As long as there's a solution to stop it happening then that's awesome, knowing why it happens in the first place is just a bonus!

Comment: Haven't been able to try it as I had to create new configurations to resolve it when it happened before, but if it happens again I'll try it and let you know!